# Standalone VUE application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

Is possible to build vuejs as a standalone app? So I am not depended on my web hotel backend services.

Basically I just don't want to start up the app through npm, but by simply open index.html from the dist folder over `file://` protocol.

My webhotel doesn't support npm and node.js.

Comment: please provide more details ?

Comment: I want to be able to just open index.html. I don't want to start with npm run serve

Comment: So you only have the local files and don't want to have it on a server o something like that? You want to have it similar to an Electron App?

Comment: Maybe this help?
Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.
  Opening index.html over file:// won't work.

I want Opening index.html over file://

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `npm run build` it will generate the `dist` directory with needed `js` and `css` files and `index.html` if you open this file in your browser without HTTP server you will have errors in browsers console like :

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    app.f5g4fd.js

to fix this open `index.html` in text editor and remove `\` at the beginning from `src` or `href` script and link tags like :

```
  <script src=/js/app.c6a4cab1.js></script>
```

should be :

```
  <script src=js/app.c6a4cab1.js></script>
```

save the file and open it over `file://`

Comment: Doesn't the app loss features?

Comment: no i usually use this way, i copy the dist directory and name it `docs` and i do the changes cited above and i deploy it to github pages, features like `axios` calls will be saved [repo](https://github.com/boussadjra/vueye-table) and [index.html](https://github.com/boussadjra/vueye-table/blob/master/docs/index.html)